# I am using dynamic form in angular 7 it gives me the ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'i'

Tags: angular, angular7

i am using angular 7 dynamic form in which i import FormBuilder and FormArray from @angular/forms
i am facing some error that i can not figure out i am new in angular

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormArray} from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

constructor(private fb:FormBuilder){}

users = this.fb.group({
user_fname:this.fb.array([]),
user_lname:this.fb.array([]),
user_conatact:this.fb.array([]),
user_email:this.fb.array([])
});
 get UserFirstName()
 {
 return this.users.get('user_fname') as FormArray;
 }
get UserLastName()
{
 return this.users.get('user_lname') as FormArray;
}
 get UserContact()
{
 return this.users.get('user_conatact') as FormArray;
}
get UserEmail()
{
 return this.users.get('user_email') as FormArray;
}
addNewUserRow()
{
this.UserFirstName.push(this.fb.control(''));
this.UserLastName.push(this.fb.control(''));
this.UserEmail.push(this.fb.control(''));
this.UserContact.push(this.fb.control(''));
}
}
```

and my component html code is

```
<div class="container">
<h1>User Registeration Form</h1>
<hr />
{{users.value | json}}
 <form [formGroup]="users">
 <div class="row">

   <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control">
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="last-name">Contact No</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="last-name">Email Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>



        <div formControlArray="user_fname" *ngFor="let fname of UserFirstName.controls; let i=index;" class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">First Name</label>
              <input type="text"  class="form-control" formControlName="i">
            </div>
        </div>

          <div formControlArray="user_lname" *ngFor="let fname of UserLastName.controls; let i=index;" class="col-md-3">
             <div class="form-group">
               <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control">
             </div>
           </div>

           <div formControlArray="user_contact" *ngFor="let fname of UserContact.controls; let i=index;" class="col-md-3">
               <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="last-name">Contact No</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control">
               </div>
             </div>

             <div formControlArray="user_email" *ngFor="let fname of UserEmail.controls; let i=index;" class="col-md-3">
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="last-name">Email Address</label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control">
                 </div>
               </div>

</div>
</form>
```

Add New Row

and it,s give me the following error
    AppComponent.html:40 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'i'

Comment: The error is because your formArray does have any form controls in it but there is HTML element for the same control hence the error. Read more here https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: can you send me where i am doing the mistak

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i am add new row that consist of user first name last name email and conatct i have a button when click on that i want to add new row for add new user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i a small **[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fhft35)** where you have a form visible to add first user and then you click add button to add more rows to add more users.
Sorry for the plain styling you can add that according to you convenience.

**Here is the HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="usersForm">
    <div *ngFor="let user of userControls; let i=index" [formGroup]="user">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
                <input formControlName="firstName" type="text" class="form-control">
     </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
                    <input formControlName="lastName"  type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="last-name">Contact No</label>
                        <input formControlName="contact" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="last-name">Email Address</label>
                            <input formControlName="email" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  <button (click)="addNew()">Add New User</button>
</form>

<h6>Form value</h6>
{{value | json }}
```

**Componenet.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormArray,FormGroup  } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  usersForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){
    this.usersForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    users: this.formBuilder.array([
        this.createUserRow()
      ])
    });
  }
  get userControls(){
    return  (this.usersForm.get('users') as FormArray).controls
  }

  get value(){
   return this.usersForm.getRawValue();
  }

  createUserRow(){
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: [null],
      lastName:[null],
      contact:[null],
      email:[null]
    })
  }

  addNew(){
     (this.usersForm.get('users') as FormArray).controls.push(this.createUserRow());
  }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: can you help me how to remove a single row

Comment: @abubakkartahir remove a single row as in like.. no form visible at the start? And sorry i'm too piled up right now may not be able to take more work.. here i occasionally come to answer question..

Comment: i am working on router but when i click on link it,s does not work here is my menu that i have define in index.html  <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item @@about">
                <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item @@blog">
                <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/blog">BLOG</a>
              </li>